# Font presentation difference between version 9 and version 10

Tags: graphics, fonts

I am trying to make presentation quality bar charts. As part of my effort, I used the code below.  Updated to eliminate font specification. The problem appears to be a rendering difference, not a font selection issue.

```
t = RandomInteger[{5, 15}, 5];
chlbl = Style[#,16] & /@ {"Toyota", "Ford", "GM", "Honda", "Other"};
BarChart[t,
  ChartElementFunction -> "GlassRectangle", 
  ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
  ChartLabels -> chlbl, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[Black,16]]
```

The chart looks good in version 9, not so good in version 10.

[image: Version 9 image]   Version 9

[image: Version 10 image]   Version 10

Comment: Looks fine on my MacBook with Mathematica v. 10.0.2  The font is heavier than your upper image, but far smoother than your lower image.  Shouldn't Georgia be a serif font? Your lower image is sans serif.

Comment: I just ran your code on v 10.0.2.0 under Windows 8.1 and obtained a plot like your first one (which I presume is the one you describe as looking good).  I had this problem myself some time ago and discovered that I had changed some default setting when using version 9.0.1.0, and this caused problems under 10.0.0.0.  Unfortunately, I do not recall the details.

Comment: Suspect this has nothing to do with `BarChart`. What happens when you evaluate `Style["Some text here", FontFamily -> "Georgia", 16]`?

Comment: In version 10.1 Style["Some text here", FontFamily->"Georgia",16] works fine. The Georgia font appears in the selection list.  With this font and many others, the rendering is still poor in Histogram (and other charts and graphs).

Answer (score 1):

**Your output looks as if *Mathematica* fails to find the font:** I have a comparable result, if I replace "Georgia" with "SomeFontThatIsNotThere" in your code, while still not quite as ugly as yours.

You might check, if Georgia is available in the Font search paths collection:

Format>Option Inspector…>Global Options>File Locations>Private Paths>"Fonts"

**If *Mathematica* does not suggest an autocompletion for "Georgia" when starting to type `FontFamily->"`, chances are, the font is not found/available.**

This output seems to prove that thought:

[image: looks bad]

---

On my system, Georgia (and all other fonts I tested) renders fine, independent of:

- notebook zoom
- `ImageSize`
- different `FontWeight`s used

[image: looks good]

However, I found, that when zooming down the notebook, the vertical axis' labels disappear (and do not reappear when resetting the zoom to 100% again), but that's a different story, I suppose.